# nvidia GPUのメモリを再起動せずに解放する方法が知りたい

Tags: python, 機械学習, chainer, memory-leaks, gpu

PCを再起動させずにメモリを解放する方法が知りたいです。
コマンド等でメモリ解放できないでしょうか？

２つのGPUを使用しており、片方は動作中のままにしたいので、
再起動や、全てのプロセスを停止させたりはしたくないです。

以下は `nvidia-smi` コマンドを実行した画面です。

[image: nvidia-smiコマンド]

●環境
OS：ubuntu14.04
GPU:GeForce GTX 1080
※python(chainer)で機械学習を実行中にエラーとなり、メモリが解放されなくなりました。

Answer (score 1):

Chainerは使ったことがありませんが、killコマンドで不要なプロセスを消せばよいらしいです。
https://qiita.com/miyamotok0105/items/033b850a205f958808e9

ゾンビプロセスを残さないようなシステム設計を検討したほうがよいかと。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。リンク先の手順を試しましたが、実行中のプロセスとエラーとなったプロセスが共通のプロセスIDをもっており、不要プロセスのみ消すことが出来ませんでした。